# Does telerik radbutton's onclick event conflict with the validationgroup?

Tags: asp.net, validation, telerik

i use validationgroup when i want to validate some textbox, but the onclick event doesn't work when add the code `validationgroup="validation1"` to the button after i click the button,why?how can i solve this problem?

```
<telerik:RadButton Width="95" ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save Order" OnClick="btnSave_Click"
                        Visible='<%# GetVisibleAuthority("Admin/CSR/Drafter/FieldCrew/PLS/ClientAdmin/ClientUser/Admin","") %>'
                        Value="" ToolTip="Move Order Status To 'New'" validationgroup="validation1">
                    </telerik:RadButton>
```

Comment: Does nobody know this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't comment so I'm trying an answer.
It seems there is a bug in the older Telerik versions, what version are you using?
I just updated my version to Q2 2013, now the buttonclick works but it won't validate in IE10... Sigh.
Anyway, just thought I'd let you know.

**Edit:** Won't validate as in doesn't care if the textbox is empty or not, even though it should be validated.

**Edit2:** You need to use an `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator />` in order to get it to work aswell though, just as a reminder.

**Edit3:** Just thought I'd let you know that I solved my issue with IE 10. Some settings on the (server) computer made IE behave strange.

Comment: I have found the reason.I have two button that contain attributes "ValidationGroup='Group1'".But there is only one button can be displayed when page load(based on some conditions).So how can i disable the validation group of the hidden buttons in backstage?

Comment: @Tangfb You need to have two different <asp:RequiredFieldValidator>, set to different things. You can set "reqValidId.Enabled = false" to match which ones should be active.